# Unable to get Session in Spring Controller when using Websockets

Tags: session, sockjs, spring-websocket

I am using Websockets SockJS with Spring MVC Framework. I tried the Stock Ticker example that's working fine but now I want to get Session in my Controller but I am unable to find a way out.

```
Client Code:
$scope.socket = new SockJS("ws/ws"); 
$scope.stompClient = Stomp.over($scope.socket); 
$scope.stompClient.connect("guest", "guest",connectCallback, errorCallback);

//in connectCallback
$scope.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/agent-sendstatus', showScreenPop);

    Java Code:
    @MessageMapping("/topic/agent-sendstatus")
        public void testmethod()
        {
            //How do i get Session here to further implement solution?

            template.convertAndSend("/topic/agent-sendstatus","bcd");
        }

Please suggest.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you are referring to the WebSocket session, Spring 4.1 lets you get the session attributes in a header of the incoming client messages which can be accessed via the `SimpMessageHeaderAccessor`.

```
@MessageMapping("/topic/agent-sendstatus")
public void testmethod(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
    String sessionId = headerAccessor.getSessionId(); // Session ID
    Map<String, Object> attrs = headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes(); // Session Attributes
    ...
}
```

Comment: This helped me although I am using Spring 4.0.6 so I tried your solution without updating Spring, it works.

Answer (score 3):

I also think you need a interceptor, you will get empty `sessionAttributes` without it.

You need to add `HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor` in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<websocket:message-broker
    application-destination-prefix="/app"
    user-destination-prefix="/user">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/websocket">
        <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor"/>
        </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
        <websocket:sockjs session-cookie-needed="true" />
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic, /message" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

And then you will be able to get session in the controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/authorization.action")
public Message authorizationAction(
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor, Message message) {
    Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes = headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes();
    System.out.println(sessionAttributes);
    // Do something with session
    return new Message(...);
}
```